# Next auth linking connections

Tags: reactjs, next.js, oauth, next-auth

So I am building an application and I want to allow a user to connect/link an oauth connection to their account but prevent them from signing in. Something similar to discord connections tab.

When I configure my next-auth file for handling the providers I need to call the signIn function with the provider name but this then tries to create an account, I want to prevent the account create and I just want it as a way someone can display their connection on their profile.

1. Is this even possible with next-auth?
2. If not what would you suggest to achieve this?

I am using next-auth to handle email:password authentication so ideally would like to use it for everything.